# How to shutdown Windows 10 PC using cortana?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I got Cortana yesterday and was getting along with it.But when I said Shutdown, it just searched Bing for Shutdown. I want Cortana to shut down my PC, how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates a shortcut that Cortana can invoke, the target of the shortcut is the Windows `shutdown.exe` utility.

1. Goto C:\Users\ {Your Username} \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
2. Create a new shortcut
3. In location, type `shutdown -s -t 10 -c "Your Comment"` (without the quotes)
4. Now name it whatever you want.

Done
`-s` is for shutting it down and `-r` for restarting it. `-t` is the timer in seconds.
`-c` is the comment which appears when going to shut down. [This is a youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtSxuvvOkF8) which shows how to do it.